# How come request.getPathInfo() in service method returns null?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, service

I wrote Front Controller Pattern and ran the test. Somehow request.getPathInfo() is returning null when it should return the path info.

**1. HTML that calls servlet**

```
<a href="tmp.do">Test link to invoke cool servlet</a>
```

**2. Map the servlet in DD.**
Anything that has .do extension (ex tmp.do) will invoke the servlet "Redirector"

```
<!-- SERVLET (centralized entry point) -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RedirectHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.masatosan.redirector.Redirector</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RedirectHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**3. The servlet that takes request from *.do**

```
 public class Redirector extends HttpServlet {

        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {
                //test - THIS RETURNS NULL!!!!
                System.out.println(request.getPathInfo());

                Action action = ActionFactory.getAction(request); //return action object based on request URL path
                String view = action.execute(request, response); //action returns String (filename) 
                if(view.equals(request.getPathInfo().substring(1))) {
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + view + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                else {
                    response.sendRedirect(view);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException("Failed in service layer (ActionFactory)", e);
            }
        }
    }//end class
```

The problem is that request.getPathInfo() returns null. Based on the Head First book,

> The servlet life cycle moves from
>   `"does not exist"` state to
>   `"initialized"` state (meaning ready
>   to service client's request) beginning
>   with its constructor. The init()
>   always completes before the first call
>   to service().

This tells me that somewhere between the constructor and init() method, the servlet is not-fully-grown servlet.

So, that means, by the time service() method is called, the servlet should be fully-grown servlet and request method should be able to call getPathInfo() and expect the valid value to return instead of null.

## UDPATE

Very interesting. (http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=657991)

**(HttpServletRequest - getPathInfo() )**

If the URL is like below:

http://www.myserver.com/mycontext/myservlet/hello/test?paramName=value.

If you web.xml discribe the servlet pattern as /mycontext/* getPathInfo() will return myservlet/hello/test and getQueryString() will return paramName=value

**(HttpServletRequest - getServletPath() )**

If the URL is like below:

http://hostname.com:80/mywebapp/servlet/MyServlet/a/b;c=123?d=789

String servletPath = req.getServletPath();

It returns "/servlet/MyServlet"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Vivien is correct. You'd like to use [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) instead (sorry, I overlooked that bit while writing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297) which you undoubtely was reading, I've updated the answer).

To clarify: `getPathInfo()` does **not** include servlet path as definied in `web.xml` (only the path thereafter) and `getServletPath()` basically returns **only** the servlet path as definied in `web.xml` (and thus not the path thereafter). If the url pattern contains a wildcard, particularly *that* part is included.

Comment: I should have looked the doc, didn't know getServletPath() exists!

Comment: Gottya so in DD, if I specify <url-pattern>/foo/*.do</url-pattern>, getPathInfo() would only get path AFTER the ".do" <br /> That means, /foo/test.do/blah?name=myname then it returns "/blah?name=myname"

Comment: `/foo/*.do` is not a valid url pattern, so it won't be able to return anything :) Even then, in theory it would only give `/blah`. It doesn't include the query string. For that you have the `getQueryString()` method (or just the usual `getParameter()` methods).

Comment: Had the very same problem when implementing with url pattern "/something/*". Thanks for the link masato-san this saved me lots of time http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqUrl.html
@BalusC: you may want to add this link your answer...it is very complementary

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html):

> Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string. This method returns null if there was no extra path information.

You don't have any path info when using a prefixed mapping (`*.do`, in your case).