# Grizzly's Request.getPathInfo returns always null?

Tags: java, http, grizzly

I'm trying to implement a custom Grizzly [HttpHandler](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.2/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpHandler.html) but fail miserably trying to simply extract the path info from the incoming requests. See the minimal example below:

```
public class PathInfoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer();
        final NetworkListener nl = new NetworkListener(
                "grizzly", "localhost", 8080);
        httpServer.addListener(nl);
        httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
                new HandlerImpl(), "/test");   
        httpServer.start();
        System.in.read();
    }

    private static class HandlerImpl extends HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void service(Request request, Response response)
                throws Exception {

            System.out.println(request.getPathInfo());
            System.out.println(request.getContextPath());
            System.out.println(request.getDecodedRequestURI());
            System.out.println(request.getHttpHandlerPath());
    }
}
```

I thought this would tell Grizzly that all incoming requests where the URL starts with "/test" should be handled by `HandlerImpl`, which seems to work so far. However, when doing a GET to `http://localhost:8080/test/foo`, this code prints the following to `stdout`:

```
null
/test
/test/foo
null
```

My main concern is the first `null`, which should be the path info. I expect it to be `foo` in this example, not `null`. Can someone explain to me:

1. why both, `getHttpHandlerPath()` and `getPathInfo()` return `null` in this example?
2. Also, I suspect the latter being a consequence of the first, is this right?
3. How can I get my hands on the "unrouted" part of the URL in Grizzly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745275/how-come-request-getpathinfo-in-service-method-returns-null

Comment: @gavenkoa The question you linked is about Servlets, while this one is not related to Servlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use asterisk in mapping (similar to Servlets) to see the correct pathInfo value.
For example please use the following mapping:

```java
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
     new HandlerImpl(), "/test/myhandler/*");
```

and make a request to `http://localhost:8080/test/myhandler/foo/bar`

and the result will be:

```
/foo/bar
/test
/test/myhandler/foo/bar
/myhandler
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this does the trick. This should definitively be part of the documentation.

Comment: This mapping corresponds to the Servlet mapping, but I agree we have to better document addHttpHandler() method to make it clear. Thank you for the feedback :)